# Module that allows access to node based on roles

Tags: 7

Is there a module that lets me simply select the roles that can have access to a node as I create it?

For example, I have a role named "BUG", I want BUG to be able to access node/5, but not any other role (including authenticated users).

I've been looking and looking and can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal offers a wide selection of [node access modules](https://drupal.org/node/270000).

Many (but not all) of these offer role based access control.

While still only in beta for D7, [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) is a module I personally use for role based node access control. I regard it as stable for role based access control.  However *do not* use it for lower resolution (user based) access control, as this mode is not yet stable.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.

One of the advantages by this module is that it is fairly straightforward to control access to individual nodes by role.

Comment: Content Access seems pretty good... I find the interface a little unintuitive though.